# event.returnvalue=false is not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I am working on an old application to make it compatible with firefox. As the old application does not uses Jquery I have to do all my stuffs using Javascript only.

I have a input field for entering date.This field should only allow 0-9 numeric values. So I have modified the code like this for making it compatible with firefox.

```
var event = window.event || ffEvent ; //ffEvent is the function argument
var intKeyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
if (intKeyCode < 48 || intKeyCode > 57){
 if(event.preventDefault){
   event.preventDefault();
 }
 else{
   event.returnValue = false;
 }
}
```

But now the problem is `event.returnValue = false` allows keys like `Backspace,Tab,Delete,Arrow buttons` where as `event.preventDefault()` does not allow these buttons. One must allow these buttons for a input field.

So is there any solutions for firefox which exactly behave same as `event.returnValue=false`

Answer (score 0):

why not use the keyCodes to check if the character is digit or not

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    var event = window.event || ffEvent ; //ffEvent is the function argument
    var intKeyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (intKeyCode > 31 && (intKeyCode < 48 || intKeyCode > 57))
         return false;

    return true;
}
```

in the keypress of input field call this event, as

```
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)
```

Comment: I want to allow buttons like delete,backspace in firefox. But event.preventDefault() doesnot allows.

Comment: that is what I am suggesting, don't even use prevenDefault(), if digits are the only thing you want to check.

Comment: Not working.I want that Date field should allow numbers and other buttons like backspace,delete,tab etc.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is skip the `event.preventDefault()` when the key is one of the keys you want to allow:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('myField').onkeypress = function (event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which,
            allowedKey = keyCode === 8  ||  // backspace
                         keyCode === 9  ||  // tab
                         keyCode === 13 ||  // enter
                         keyCode === 37 ||  // left
                         keyCode === 39 ||  // right
                         keyCode === 46 ||  // del
                         (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57);
        if (!allowedKey) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myField" />
```